# Printf not replacing format string parameters

Tags: c, printf, minix

I'm trying to do a homework assignment involving modifying some kernel code in minix and i'm having the strangest issue i've ever seen.

I'm modifying alloc.c on the pm server (for those of you familiar with minix) and i've added a global variable to the top of the file:

```
PUBLIC int logging = 0;
```

Then later on i'm trying to read the variable in one of my functions i've added to the kernel:

```
PUBLIC int do_setalloc(void)
{
  printf("logging = %i\n", logging");
  return (OK);
}
```

I then have a test program which runs this code outside the kernel space:

```
int main(void)
{
  message m;
  m.m1_i1 = 1;
  m.m1_i2 = 1;
  _syscall(MM,69,&m);
  return 0;
}
```

This is the output when this code gets run:

```
logging = %i
```

Printf isn't actually replacing the %i formatting with the actual value of the integer, I am tearing my hair out here and this assignment is due soon! Help!

Comment: +1 for finding an ugly Minix bug. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't think "%i" was a valid format conversion; the most commonly-used tag to print an int is "%d". But the printf manpage I just looked at claimed %i was a synonym for %d. Perhaps the minix printf doesn't define it.

Comment: Probably should have just been a comment :)

Comment: Indeed, although apparently, based on comments elsewhere from the OP, this was indeed the problem -- his minix printf implementation doesn't use "%i".

Comment: The reason `%i` exists is for alignment with `scanf` formats. While `%i` and `%d` are identical for `printf`, with `scanf` the former supports hex and octal like C integer constants, while the latter is exclusively decimal.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it `%d` for an integer in printf?

Comment: Both: `d, i   The int argument is converted to signed decimal notation.`

Comment: %i is a synonym (%d - decimal base 10, %i - integer base 10).

Comment: Wow, you're absolutely right. Thank you! Aparrantly %i works in C++ but not C, which explains a LOT (I was doing some testing to try and help me figure it out but I was using a C++ compiler, so it was working on that but not in my actual kernel which is C)

Comment: @Ring, note that `%i` works fine _in userland_, but the Minix Kernel development team must have decided against supporting both for some reason. Don't blame this on C. :)

Comment: Yeah, thought I'd throw it out there, but was waiting for the downvotes because of some Minix thing I had no idea about.